# "Optimiser" vs "optimizer"?

Tags: usage, spelling, transatlantic-differences

I have seen words which are spelled either with a "z" or with a "s"  like "optimizer" and " optimiser".  I thought that the ones with "z" are wrong but on searching the web I found that both are correct. Why so? Is there any difference in the use also?

Answer (score 12):

"-ize" is the common AmE suffix, while in BrE "-ise" is more commonly used:

***[-ize](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ize&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - word-forming element used to make verbs, Middle English -isen, from Old French -iser, from Late Latin -izare, from Greek -izein, a verb-forming element denoting the doing of the noun or adjective to which it is attached.
> - English picked up the French form, but partially reverted to the correct Greek -z- spelling from late 16c. ***In Britain, despite the opposition to it (at least formerly) of OED, Encyclopaedia Britannica, the "Times of London," and Fowler, -ise remains dominant.***
> - Fowler thinks this is to avoid the difficulty of remembering the short list of common words not from Greek which must be spelled with an -s- (such as advertise, devise, surprise).***

(Etymonline)

[optimise](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optimise%3Aeng_us_2012%2Coptimise%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coptimise%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coptimise%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) vs [optimize](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optimize%3Aeng_us_2012%2Coptimize%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coptimize%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coptimize%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) usages in AmE vs BrE.

Comment: And in Canada it's a crapshoot which one you'd see more.

Comment: @SandyChapman When you type both into your favorite word processor, which, if either, gets flagged as a spelling mistake?

Answer (score 2):

According to NGram, both *optimizer* and *optimiser* are used in [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optimizer%2Coptimiser&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Coptimizer%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boptimizer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOptimizer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOPTIMIZER%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Coptimiser%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boptimiser%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOptimiser%3B%2Cc0). But in [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=optimizer%2Coptimiser&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Coptimizer%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boptimizer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOptimizer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOPTIMIZER%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Coptimiser%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Boptimiser%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOptimiser%3B%2Cc0), the latter isn't used.